# Is it possible to make font Awesome icon as button in Placeholder?

Tags: php, html, css, font-awesome

I've search alot about making normal Font Awesome icon as button in a textbox's Placeholder , but i couldn't find the solution.
I've designed a login Form has already a Font Awesome icon in placeholder as normal text :

```
<input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder='Password  &#xf070;'/>
```

[image]

**So** can i use this icon  as button so i can add then Jquery code to show the password later?

[**Demo - CSS and HTML code**](https://jsfiddle.net/fLwLz4um/) 
*Thank you.*

Comment: Please share your html and css code with working example..

Comment: refer : https://codepen.io/huckbit/pen/rezezb?editors=1100#0

Comment: @UpendraJoshi this is what i already have in my code this didnt make the icon as button , anyway thank you

Comment: @MinalChauhan updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can used `a` tag with `position: absolute`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.hide-password').click(function(){     
     $(this).toggleClass('show');
  });
});
```

```css
.hide-password {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 6px;
    z-index: 10;
    color: #666;
}
.hide-password.show .fa:before {
    content: "\f06e";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="col-sm-4">
   <form class="">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputUser">User</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputUser" placeholder="User Name">      
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPwd">Password</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPwd" placeholder="Password">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="hide-password"><i class="fa fa-eye-slash"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
  </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thats exactly what i was looking for from a long time really thank you so much! , what **.fa:before**  and **z-index** does ?

Comment: `z-index` used for visible and high order than other element and `.fa:before` used for change the icon

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Comment: `javascript:void(0)` is actually a bad practice. Because it evaluates javascript every time you click. http://web.archive.org/web/20011020004048/http://jibbering.com/faq/#_424 . You should use a button if you want to make it clickable.

Comment: @pbibergal if u guys voted my Question up i'll be thankful just for my next badge point. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you do it. Wrap your form control with div and make it `position: relative` and inside put an `input` and a `button` with `position: absolute; right: 0;`

Hide the button with `if($('input').val().length > 0) { $('button').addClass('hidden')}`

```
<style>
    .input-wrap {position: relative}
    .input-wrap > button {position: absolute; right: 0;}
</style>
<script>
    $('.input-wrap input').on('keyup', function() {
        if($(this).val().length > 0) $(this).next().addClass('hidden');
        else $(this).next().removeClass('hidden');
    });
</script>
<div class="input-wrap">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="your awesome placeholder">
    <button onclick="togglePassVisible()">&#xf070;</button>
</div>
```

Comment: not what i was looking for but anyway thank you man , voted up :)